# Remove anchor tag with ID attribute by regex

Tags: c#, html, regex

Remove anchor tag with ID attribute by regex from an HTML string

Example .

```
<div>
    <p>
        Test code
    </p>
    <a id =some value></a>
    <a href=URL ></a>
</div>
```

Have to remove anchor tag with ID attribute.
Output should be :

```
<div>
    <p>
        Test code
    </p>
    <a href=URL ></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You should show your efforts by showing what have you tried so far with what was the output vs expected output. Will increase the chances to get the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for this instead of using Regex.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
var Anchors = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
foreach (var tag in Anchors)
{
    if(tag.Attributes["id"] != null) 
    {
        tag.Remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want it in regex only